# Only accept positive integers using try catch and while

Tags: java, user-input

I'm writing a script where the user can only input positive integers. I'm using a scanner with try catch and a while loop. The loop is to keep asking the user for a correct input.

I can check for negative integers, but what about strings or some other crazy stuff?

```
    int price = 0;
    Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
    try {
        System.out.println("Enter max price: ");
        price = input.nextInt();
        if (price > 0) {
            input.close();
        } else {
            while (price < 0) {
                System.out.println("Negative values not allowed");
                System.out.println("Enter max price: ");
                price = input.nextInt();
            }
            input.close();
        }
    } catch (InputMismatchException e1) {

    }
```

I'm kind of stuck at the catch part..

Comment: Read the whole line with `nextLine()` and use `Integer.parseInt()` to attempt to parse an `int`.

Comment: Also, you don't want to close that Scanner if you plan on reading input later. Just as a heads up.

Comment: If you **have** to use `try-catch` construct then you will be catching the exception thrown by [`nextInt`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Scanner.html#nextInt()) and producing error message and continuing with the execution, but the entire `try-catch block` should be inside `while`.

Comment: @PM77-1 but what will I be looping through?

Comment: The same `while(price < 0)` as you have now. Only `nextInt()` will be wrapped in `try-catch`.  I believe that using `hasNextInt()` *proactively* is a better choice, but if your assignment is on handling exceptions, then you do it the way I described.

Comment: Is it that obvious that this is homework? ;)
But no, the assignment is not about try-catch blocks. So i will do that instead

Comment: Yes, it's obvious. If professional programmers start asking such basic questions ...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Invoke `input.hasNextInt()` to check if the next token is actually an integer. There is a lot of useful methods in `Scanner`, so I'd advise [taking a look at the docs](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/util/Scanner.html).

Comment: If you do this and want to check for it being positive in the same line, make sure you put the latter check AFTER making sure it is an int: `if (input.hasNextInt() && input.parseInt() > 0)` not the other way around.  But... you should probably do that on two separate lines anyway.